# force database connections to re-connect

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

I'm using hibernate with c3p0 for connection pooling.

The problem we're facing is that we periodically perform database upgrades which do not take effect for active connections - therefore running applications need to purge open connections and re-connect.

I know there is a maxAge for connections in c3p0, but i don't think it would be wise to set this to a value less than 30 seconds.

is there any mechanism by which we can tell applications to disconnect/reconnect immediately?

I'm not sure how but maybe the test query could be leveraged?

ideas welcome.

p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c3p0 PooledDataSources offer a `hardReset()` method and a series of softReset methods, which will replace all Connections in pools with new Connections. See

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html

`hardReset()` is sure and certain and disruptive: it will `close()` Connections from under clients in all pools that the DataSource manages.

softReset is gentler: you can reset only a single pool if you wish, and Connections aren't `close()`ed out from beneath clients, clients may continue to use them normally and then they are quietly discarded rather than returned to the pool.

[Note that one c3p0 DataSource may manage multiple pools if you have called `getConnection( user, password )`, as well as `getConnection()`. Connections authenticated to different users must be segregated into different pools.]

In all likelihood what you'll want is to call `softResetAllUsers()`. Just cast your c3p0 DataSource to `PooledDataSource` (in `com.mchange.v2.c3p0`) and call the method.

Comment: I have a question. Why does after executing `softReset(username, password)`, it will attempt to reconnect again. The failed login counter increases and doesn't stop until I restart the whole web app. thanks..  I wonder what is happening here.

Comment: It won't try indefinitely, but will go a while. softReset(...) leaves pending asynchronous tasks still pending from the old pool, waiting to die their own soft death. since the authentication credentials are no longer good, any pending Connection acqusition tasks will be repeated [acquireRetryAttempts](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#acquireRetryAttempts) times every [acquireRetryDelay](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#acquireRetryDelay) milliseconds, for every pending acquisition series (of which there may be multiple).

Comment: I've added a check, so that these acquisition attempts notice that their pool has been invalidated and give up without retrying. If you want, feel free to try 0.9.6-pre1-SNAPSHOT, available on the sonatype/Maven central snapshot repo.